# Why are my ocean/glass shaders not being rendered properly?

Tags: rendering, glass, ocean-simulation

I am very confused about my rendering output.
I'm working on a scene with an ocean modifier used on a plane. I also attached a simple Glass BSDF to it to achieve the desired appearance.

In the "pre-rendering" everything looks fine, but every time I try to render it I get this weird output, some parts of the ocean are rendered correctly, but with the rest it seems that it doesn't apply the Glass bsdf to it.

[Download .blend file](https://we.tl/t-R0iSXmNv1Y)

[image: This is how the output looks]

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Hello :). There's not enough info provided. It could be material setup, modifier setup, hidden object in a scene or something else. Please add more images to ilustrate your settings and add what you tried so far to solve the issue :).

Comment: Also, add the blend file if u can. It will make things much easier

Comment: Hi! Im sorry :) ive added some screenshots + the blend file!
I didnt try much since i dont know where to start. What i tried is to setup everything new, i also played around with tile size and ambient occlusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just accidentally found out, i was having a not-displayed older object lying beneath the other object and intersecting at some areas.